# Kubuntu won't lock

Tags: kubuntu, kde, lock-screen, lock, kde4

When I close the screen of my netbook in Kubuntu, it doesn't lock when I reopen, and when I press the lock button, nothing happens. I have KScreenSaver configured, and all the drivers work fine, so how do I get my computer to lock?

Answer (score 2):

i had to install the `laptop-mode-tools package` to get mine to lock.

i've now been able to set up my laptop to hibernate on lid close without any trouble.

use muon-package manager or `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools` to install

EDIT:
i've noticed an issue hibernating after my update to precise and thought it was just a hick-up caused by one my customization. but it's a "feature" added to 12.04.

From 12.04, hibernation is disabled by default for all Ubuntu OSes, you need to create a file and add some configuration data to it as per [this official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html).

Answer (score 0):

Activate krunner at start of KDE, log out and log in. (System settings -> Startup & sessions (?) -> Autostart) ... or run krunner (in konsole) and test again.